# Android AudioManager not working on Samsung 4.0.4

Tags: android, volume

Currently calling AudioManager to change the volume on my app - works on nexus, hudl, and samsung galaxy s5 - However, when I run the following code on the Samsung Galaxy 10"inch running android 4.0.4 the volume does not change unless the actual hard key for the volume is pressed in.

```
         myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

         myAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,level,AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

Any ideas why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that works on different versions of android and makes (nexus,samsung, hudl, samsung galaxy 10") is the following:

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.adjustSteamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

To decrease the volume you just replace AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE with AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER.

The setStreamVolume I have found does not carry across the android versions or makes that have been tested.

Answer (score 0):

Call `isVolumeFixed` to check if device supports that functionality. [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int))

> This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed().

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working for me on samsung devices.

```
public static boolean changeStreamVolume(int sign) {
        final AudioManager am = (AudioManager)ApplicationAdapter.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        final int currentVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        final int maxVolume = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        if (sign == 1 && currentVolume >= maxVolume) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (sign == -1 && currentVolume <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        // Why 11? Why not? :-)
        final int delta = (maxVolume >= 11? maxVolume / 11  : 1) * sign;
        int newVolume = (currentVolume + delta > maxVolume ? maxVolume : currentVolume + delta);
        if (newVolume < 0) {
            newVolume = 0;
        }
        am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, newVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        return true;
    }
```